# How do I sort dates into an array from a URL list?

Tags: python, arrays, url, split

I am trying to create an array from multiple urls to sort the URL into each week. How can I use the array functions to do this? I know to split up the dates in the URL I use the split function:

array = url.split('/')

But how can I sort them into each week? The URLs look like this :

URL: http://www.nytimes.com/2016/04/18/us/politics/focus-on-chief-justice-as-supreme-court-hears-immigration-challenge.html

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to isolate the date part of your URL.

Assuming all your URLs look the same (i.e `https://somedomain.tld/year/month/day/wathever-else), you have several solutions: regex, split by slashes, and so on. Be careful to pick the solution that is most suited to your problem, as if all the URLs have a different format, this step might not work as expected.

Then, you can use the `datetime.strptime` function to turn your string date into a datetime object. See more here : https://docs.python.org/fr/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Once you have the datetime object for each URL, you'll be able to sort the array any way you like.

So :

1. Extract the date string from URL using any method suited to your problem
2. For each of these date string, use `strptime` to turn them into datetime
3. Sort your list using the datetime objects

If you come up with some code, we might be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

the idea is to extract the date from the url and to sort the url list by the date.

see below

```
import datetime

urls = [
    'http://www.nytimes.com/2016/04/18/us/politics/focus-on-chief-justice-as-supreme-court-hears-immigration-challenge.html',
    'http://www.nytimes.com/2015/03/18/us/politics/focus-on-chief-justice-as-supreme-court-hears-immigration-challenge.html',
    'http://www.nytimes.com/2017/04/18/us/politics/focus-on-chief-justice-as-supreme-court-hears-immigration-challenge.html',
    'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/12/18/us/politics/focus-on-chief-justice-as-supreme-court-hears-immigration-challenge.html',
    'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/04/18/us/politics/focus-on-chief-justice-as-supreme-court-hears-immigration-challenge.html']

url_parts = [(url, url.split('/')) for url in urls]
tmp = []
for url_pair in url_parts:
    tmp.append((url_pair[0], datetime.datetime(int(url_pair[1][3]), int(url_pair[1][4]), int(url_pair[1][5]))))
final = [u[0] for u in sorted(tmp, key=lambda u: u[1])]
for url in final:
    print(url)
```

output

```
http://www.nytimes.com/2011/04/18/us/politics/focus-on-chief-justice-as-supreme-court-hears-immigration-challenge.html
http://www.nytimes.com/2011/12/18/us/politics/focus-on-chief-justice-as-supreme-court-hears-immigration-challenge.html
http://www.nytimes.com/2015/03/18/us/politics/focus-on-chief-justice-as-supreme-court-hears-immigration-challenge.html
http://www.nytimes.com/2016/04/18/us/politics/focus-on-chief-justice-as-supreme-court-hears-immigration-challenge.html
http://www.nytimes.com/2017/04/18/us/politics/focus-on-chief-justice-as-supreme-court-hears-immigration-challenge.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution with example:

```
import datetime

url = "http://www.nytimes.com/2016/04/28/us/politics/focus-on-chief-justice-as-supreme-court-hears-immigration-challenge.html"
url2 = "http://www.nytimes.com/2016/04/23/us/politics/focus-on-chief-justice-as-supreme-court-hears-immigration-challenge.html"

array = url.split("/")
array2 = url2.split("/")

x = datetime.datetime(int(array[3]), int(array[4]), int(array[5]))
x2 = datetime.datetime(int(array2[3]), int(array2[4]), int(array2[5]))


listing = [x,x2]
print(sorted(listing))
#[datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 23, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 28, 0, 0)]
```

You can of course do this in loop with many urls, sorted will sort your datetime objects, there is no build in method to determine week of year if that is what you wanted, you will need to translate these datetimes to a week of given year.